# Passing current JQuery object to TypeScript arrow function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, arrow-functions

I have a JQuery code snippet written in the `ngOnInit` of my Angular component. The purpose of that is to fire a method when a file is selected in the template html.

Following JQuery has been written in `ngOnInit`. Note that it uses an arrow function.

```
$(document.body).on("change.bs.fileinput", ".fileinput-exists", () => {
    alert("fired");
    // do file upload stuff
    // for that, access the current input field and get the uploaded file
});
```

In order to handle the file, I need to access it. For that, I need to have current input field accessible in the arrow function.

How can I pass it? I tried with `$(this)` as the arrow function parameter. It gave me a compile error.

OR

Should I pass the event?  `(event : EventTarget)` as the arrow function parameter.

Comment: Arrow functions don't let you use the caller's `this`.

Comment: One of the main uses of the arrow function is so the scope does not change for the this, but in your case you are saying you want to change the scope.  So the arrow function is not what you want to use in this case.  Use a normal function.  Otherwise, pass in the event and then you can do event.currentTarget or event.target

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "issue" is with the arrow functions. Actually is not an issue but it's a feature. Using arrow functions you won't change the context of the `this`, how normal functions do. 
So if you want to use an arrow function, select again the element through a selector, because you are not able to use the `$(this)` inside. 
Otherwise (better) you can access the `event.currentTarget` through jQuery, as you outlined. 
But if your component is associated to the same input field, you should be able to access that just using angular, through the `$element` reference (that is much more better)

Here an example using the `event.currentTarget`:

```
$(document.body).on("change.bs.fileinput", ".fileinput-exists", (event) => {
    alert($(event.currentTarget));
    // do file upload stuff
    // for that, access the current input field and get the uploaded file
});
```

Comment: the element is a dynamic one. It wont refer the same element again and again.

Comment: what do you mean? if you have a component associated to an element, and then you have multiple instances of that element/component, the $element will actually refers every time to the current/correct one. 
By the way saying that without seeing the code is pretty hard

Comment: I thought the word 'component' in your answer referred to Angular2 component. You are not referring to it by that word , right?

Comment: What I meant is: If you created a component, that is actually the one which holds your input with this behavior, using the `$element` you will reference to that HTML.

Comment: I think `event.currentTarget` is the way for me. Can you give me a code suggestion on how to use that inside the arrow function?

Comment: sure, changing the answer. Lets try that, please check it I am not able to test it at the moment

Comment: changed it please test it and let me know, I can't test it right now

Comment: I think it should be `alert(event.currentTarget)` instead of  ` alert($(event.currentTarget))`. However, how can I access the file using this.

Comment: it depends if you want it wrapped with a jQuery object or as a simple HTML element. Latter, without $. Otherwise with $. What do you want to access? the current file the user set in the input?

Comment: $(event.currentTarget).val() should give you it, but again I am coding "by mind" please test it :)

Comment: p.s. of course this assuming that the current element we are talking about, the one who fires the event, is actually the input file

Comment: Thank you very much.. :) Accepting this as the answer. I learned a lot from this. Thank you again. :) :)

Comment: No Problem, I am happy it helped you :)